# If input is checked not working

Tags: jquery

I want to make jQuery shoot an action triggered by a click or pressed key only WHILE `input#show1` is checked. The way I tried it below seems to be the most simple way to check if the input is checked but it doesn't work somehow.
Any help what I did wrong in my code is appreciated!

```
<script>
if ($('input#show1').is(':checked')) {
    alert("show1 is checked");
}
</script>

<input type="radio" id="show1" name="group"> 
<label for="show1">Show</label>
<input type="radio" id="hide1" name="group" checked>
<label for="hide1">Hide</label>
```

Comment: the code in the question will check if the radio button `show1` is checked while the page loads. since the code is placed above the input element, and has no instruction to run after all the elements are ready, it will not find the input(because it hasnt been created yet) and will do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options here, either you execute the conditional check on DOM load or you check on change. You **have to** wait on the document to be loaded, which you can do by using a `$(document).ready()` call. Calling the function on `click` as mplungjan suggested will work as well, though I don't like it. You only want something to happen when the value changes from unchecked to checked, and not when it's checked and it's clicked again. Therefore you can use `change`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function checker() {
        if ($('input#show1').is(':checked')) {
            alert("show1 is checked");
        }
    }
    checker();
    $('input#show1').change(checker);
});
```

This code will check the value on page load, and will also watch for changes a user makes. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/r042d1hz/), click "show". [In this one](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/r042d1hz/2/), the alert will show on page load because I added the check attribute to Show.

---

### Following your edit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27 && $('input#show1').is(':checked')) {
           alert('Esc key pressed.');
        }
    });
});
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/r042d1hz/4/).

---

### Another edit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
           checker();
        }
    });

    $("#control").click(function() {
        checker();        
    });

    function checker() {
        if ($('input#show1').is(':checked')) {
            alert("It's checked.");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Bummer, mate.");
        }
    }
});
```

Seet it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/r042d1hz/6/).

Comment: I might have not expressed myself well enough about what I want.
To go more into detail:
I want another function to be triggered by pressing Esc Key (or clicking some div). And I want this function to shoot each time Esc Key is pressed, but only  WHILE `input#show1` is in the state 'checked'.

Comment: This actually works for me now!
But I have two handlers, one keyup (for Esc Key) and one click function (to trigger same action by a click on specific divs) .
Is there a way to wrap this in an IF statement around them, so both of them only can get triggered when `input#show1` is `checked`?
I simply tried packing both functions into
`if ( $('input#show1').is(':checked') ) {` but its not working.

Comment: Great, that was what I was looking for, now I got all my function under one roof.  Thanks for taking the time helping me! : )

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a radio, it will be checked when clicked. So

```
$(function() { // at load
  $("#show1").on("click",function() {
    alert("checked"); // when clicked
  });
  if ($("#show1").is(":checked") { // at load time
    alert("Checked at page load");
  }
});
```

My guess is, not having seen your other code, that you want

```
$(function() { // at load
  $("#someDiv").toggle($("#show1").is(":checked"));
  $(".group").on("click",function() {
    $("#someDiv").toggle(this.id=="show1");
  });

});
```

Comment: Since currently it can only be checked if the button is clicked and the page reloaded, I thought perhaps not

Comment: What I want is to trigger a function by either a click on a Div or some pressed Button, but only WHILE the state of `#show1` is `'checked'`.

Answer (score 0):

`#show1` is not checked at all in your `HTML` markup. I assume you meant to check for `#hide1`.

Also, you'd need to wrap your code around

```
jQuery(function($) { // same as doing $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('input#hide1').is(':checked')) {
        alert("hide1 is checked");
    }
});
```

To wait for the DOM to be ready.

If you don't, the javascript code will be executed **before** the `<input/>` element is even created.